# Script files in index.html are working home page but they aren't working on other child screen

Tags: reactjs

My script files are active on firspage (homepage) but it is not working when i try to open other screenpage

scripts:

```
    <script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/plugins.min.js"></script>

    <script src="/js/functions.js"></script>
  </body>
```

**For example:**

```
<BrowserRouter>  
   <Route path="/" component={HomeScreen} exact></Route>
   <Route path="/product/:id" component={ProductScreen} exact></Route>
    ....
```

script files are working very well on "localhost:3000"
but i go to "localhost:3000/product/hj2k131231" (e.g.) any script doesnot work

Answer (score 0):

Route components are not loading the page again so your scrips/jquery only executes once page loads.

Some possible fixes are:

1. Re run the scripts against the selectors you want every time https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange
2. Make all Route reload with a combination of [SSR](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html) and [StaticRouter](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/StaticRouter)

EDIT:
With react router you can use (withRrouter)[https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter] HOC to listen for location changes.

```js
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

const NotifyRouteChange = withRouter(({ history }) => {
  useEffect(() => history.listen(refreshJqueryPlugins, []);
  return null;
});

function refreshJqueryPlugins(){
  $('...').doSomething()
}
```

```js
<BrowserRouter>
<NotifyRouteChange />
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: That is useful if i wrote the jquery but i integrated template so there are hundreds codes.I can not work with this method.I need a method where I can export the script file.Am i rihgt?